# A software engineer and an accountant

Tags: resume, new-job, careers

I currently work as a senior software engineer. During my spare time I have learned financial accounting and have managed to get myself certified as an accountant. My question is, will there be any value addition to my profile by including 'Accountant' profile into my CV as I am applying for finance related programming jobs.

This is what I have in my mind to add to my profile

> A certified Accountant. Having worked in Banks for a majority of my career, Finance interests me and I learn accounting in my spare time.

I certainly do not want to flaunt my learning skills by adding this into my CV but was wondering if this would make any difference in the finance industry when my resume is being scanned by potential employers.

Comment: For certifications see [this answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36812/when-showing-certifications-should-i-group-by-subject-or-certification-level) for an example. I don't think writing "Having worked in Banks..." etc. fits here.

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to use terms like certified accountant make sure that you meet the definition of the term.

Having domain experience is a good thing. Some of the people who are applying will have it, but others will not. So you should mention it in your CV/resume, especially if the document is being prepared to target a specific company or industry.

Domain knowledge and experience is also something to highlight in the cover letter.